# Android: Sample data presentation is not String

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, layout

I have the following sample data structure
[image]

My layout, as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:padding="16dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/avatar"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@sample/posts.json/data/authorAvatar"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_post"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/author"
            android:layout_width="294dp"
            android:layout_height="23dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/published"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/avatar"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/avatar"
            android:text="@sample/posts.json/data/author" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/published"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/avatar"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/author"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/avatar"
            android:text="@sample/posts.json/data/published" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="344dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="344dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_more_vert_24" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The problems i'm trying to resolve is the data from json is presented as the links.
Would you please help me to understand where i made a mistake?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you have to load data from a JSON file, there are a couple of ways of doing that, move the file into the assets directory, read the file, deserialize the object to either a json object or user-defined object, and then you can assign it to the views by code if you want to do it via XML data binding can help you (as a new android developer I would not recommend this).